# How to do simple required validation in angular Modal Popup?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-forms

A User opens a Modal and shouldn't be able to Click Ok until he fills in the required input

I tried what is mentioned in [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#template-driven-validation) but doesn't work

Here is the [**working Demo stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-alr2fg?file=app/dialog-overview-example.html) that needs to implement this

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';

export interface DialogData {
  animal: string;
  name: string;
}

/**
 * @title Dialog Overview
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-overview-example',
  template: `<button mat-raised-button (click)="openDialog()">Pick one</button>
  <li *ngIf="animal">
    You chose: <i>{{animal}}</i>
  </li>`
})
export class DialogOverviewExample {

  animal: string;
  name: string;

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) { }

  openDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
      width: '250px',
      data: { name: this.name, animal: this.animal }
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed');
      this.animal = result;
    });
  }

}

@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-overview-example-dialog',
  templateUrl: 'dialog-overview-example-dialog.html',
})
export class DialogOverviewExampleDialog {

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogOverviewExampleDialog>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData) { }

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

}


/**  Copyright 2019 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
    Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
    can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license */
```

**dialog.html**

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Hi {{data.name}}</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content>
  <p>What's your favorite animal?</p>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input required matInput name="myInput" [(ngModel)]="data.animal">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button (click)="onNoClick()">No Thanks</button>
  <!-- <button mat-button [disabled]="myInput.errors.required" [mat-dialog-close]="data.animal" cdkFocusInitial>Ok</button> -->
     <button mat-button  [mat-dialog-close]="data.animal" cdkFocusInitial>Ok</button> 

</div>
```

Comment: You should open the console in your stackbitz, and then fix all the errors you're getting.

Comment: @R.Richards fixed it that was just to show the documentation stuff was causing those errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about simply disable the ok button when the user doesn't fill any data ? Something like this :

```
<button mat-button [disabled]="!data.animal"  [mat-dialog-close]="data.animal" cdkFocusInitial>Ok</button>
```

[Stackblick demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-alr2fg-tz6knl?file=app/dialog-overview-example-dialog.html)

You can also wrap the input inside `<form #form="ngForm">...</form>` tag and check if the form is valid `[disabled]="form.invalid"`

Comment: Thanks I was missing the form tags didnt knew that i thought `<mat-form-field>` was enough

Comment: This will give a warning in the console because you are trying to focus when you initialize your pop up. You will get something like this "Element matching '[cdkFocusInitial]' is not focusable."